# How to inject "FontAwesomeIcon" in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, font-awesome

I am trying to do something to the effect of :

```
(if navbar is open){
//display close icon
navToggle.innerHTML = "<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'times']} />";
}
else{
//display burger icon
navToggle.innerHTML = "<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'bars']} />";
}
```

I am doing this in the onclick listener for burger icon.

I am using the "react-fontawesome" library. The icons work fine, but when the javascript tries to inject them they don't appear, i guess as they are a react component and not rendered by react library. How do i acheive this if possible with some other method? should i have two icons already rendered, and then i can just toggle the css of one or other, instead of injecting them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React you would use them like so:

```
const MyComponent = ({ navBarOpen }) => (
   navBarOpen? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'times']} /> : <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'bars']} />
);
```